# How to read from tab delimited file to C# in asp .net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, csv

**I would like to read from tab delimited file to C# code of asp .net web app.** I developed a web app that is based on VS 2017 Web app (File, New, Web site, C#, ASP .NET Web Forms site). It receives several integer and text values from the user, an image, passes it on server side to a java.exe external application which writes the image analysis to a java Derby database (started with a command 
java.exe -Xmx2G -jar filename.jar 5206 JAVA_DB org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver jdbc:derby:C:/folder ...). The web app runs on Windows Server 2016, in IIS, I installed SQL Server 2016 Express. For the moment users log in, get the file processed. Java app (commercial) and IIS run on the same Server machine.
Now I wanted to get the record from the database to C# in web app. Finally I would like to store user entered values with image analysis to an user account for future analysis.

1. First I looked for a way to connect from SQL Server to Derby database but found no driver to do that. The closest is of EasySoft ([Easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_jdbc_gateway/index.html#section=tab-3)  as far I understand, but being 500 GBP, I left it for the future). There is a connector to reach SQL from Derby, from Microsoft, but it seems the other way around. For the moment I gave up, but in the future I would like to get some solution to develop mobile app that reaches the database. For the moment I do not know enough Java to develop a plugin for this commercial java app that writes to SQL server.

   2. As the java app and IIS are on the same machine, I may access directly directory structure of the database and this is the temporary solution I work now on. The data file is a tab delimited file with first 7 rows starting with #, 8th row is column names (there are 36 columns of data), and 9th row with values (text, integer and real values). There is no more rows. I can easily read the file to Excel as tab delimited, and the three values I am interested are in N9 (column 14, row 9), AE9 (column 31, row 9), and AH9 (column 34, row 9). All image data come the same format, the file path is the catch. It is tempting to try to read this as tab delimited file in some kind of Excel import without Excel, and refer by column # and row # in C# of the web app. I have seen several LinQ examples, but they seem to need a header first row and then same number of data as the first row.

I am new to programming (say, returning from Borland Pascal, after 30 years of doing something else), so please be patient with my ignorance. Any Microsoft Virtual Academy course or something like Channel 9 etc course suggestion for developing such an app is highly appreciated. I need to finish the app by the end of August, so I do not need it to be elegant, just working.

Any suggestion to solve point 1 or 2 is appreciated.

Regards
Marcin

Comment: Try having a look at this library:
http://www.filehelpers.net/

I've only used it once myself, but it strikes me as being extremely easy and flexible to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a magic connection string that will treat the delimited file as a database provider. Here is a code example that reads a file named `fileName` and returns it as a `DataTable`.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + ";Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=TabDelimited\"");
conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "]";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet("CSV File");
adapter.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
return ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Dear John. I got your example working to some extent: adapter.Fill(ds); generates an error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.'

Comment: Dear John. I got your example working to some extent: adapter.Fill(ds); generates an error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.' The file is Full Access in Windows. If I comment that line and proceed, I do not see the way to access the data in that table. When I try ds.Tables.Count it gives zero. File is not empty, but starts with 8 lines without tabs like that: #some text [CRLFother text[CRLF.. //FirstHeader [tab]second header[tab] ..[CRLF]data1[tab]data2[tab]...[CRLF]. Help is very much appreciated. Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved. Here is the code from VS 2017. I created a console application named VOISTATread. The file *.voistat is produced by java.exe and is in Derby database. 
The file is like that (9 lines altogether) - Hash replaces actual sign not to get Heading:

```
# PMOD_VOI_STATISTICS                           
# FORMAT[UNI]                   
# DATE_TIME[2017.08.07_13:04:45]                    
# VERSION[3.901]                            
# AXIS[Experiment][VOI][TAC][]                  
# VOXEL_FRACTION_MODE[0]                    
# DATA 
// Component [string]   File [string]   PatientName [string]    PatientID [string]  PatientInfo [string]    StudyDescription [string]   SeriesDescription [string]  StudyDate [date_time]   Color [0xARGB]  VoiName(Region) [string]    Time [seconds]  Averaged [1/1]  Sd [1/1]    Volume [ccm]    Total(SUM) [1/1]    Total(AVR*VOL) [(1/1)*(ccm)]    Min [1/1]   Max [1/1]   NumberOfPixels [voxels] NumberOfEffectivePixels [voxels]    HotAveraged(5) [1/1]    Stdv [1/1]  Q1 [1/1]    Median [1/1]    Q3 [1/1]    AreaUnderCurve [(1/1)*(seconds)]    HypoxiaIndex [1/1]  HypoxicVolume [ccm] NumberOfNaNs [1/1]  VolumeWithoutNaNs [ccm] SurfaceArea [cm2]   Sphericity [1/1]    DiameterMax [cm]    FractalDimension [1/1]  FD_LConfidenceInterval [1/1]    FD_HConfidenceInterval [1/1]
C:/Pmod3.8/data/DCMINSAH1/IMAGE_15_418472066475064.zip/IMAGE_1_418451934181564.image    IMAGE_1_418451934181564 TEACHINGFILE-CT-10697   TEACHINGFILE-CT-10697   birthDate = 19480325, size = 0.0, weight = 0.0, sex = F TC CEREBRAL CON/SIN CONTRASTE   Craneo  5.0  H31s |> NORMALIZED to Head CT reference 1mm  CU [Gauss]    20130424_113833.046 ff0000ff    Thr_60.0_80.0   22.4720165  68.55565556 5.484521182 67.401  4620719.74  4620.71974  59.95684814 80.04032898 67401   67401   80.03869019 5.484561868 63.66357422 68.33154297 72.99787903 3081.167646 1   67.401  0   67.401  1206.685689 0.066374438 17.66069081 2.164787075 2.004986778 2.324587372
```

The main part Program.cs is like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using FileHelpers;
using FileHelpers.Events;

namespace VOISTATread
{
// string delimiterString = "\t";
class Program
{
    //private static DataTable[] ar;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fileNamePath = @"C:\Pmod.data\data\DATABASES\SAHCNA1\data\M8\20170807\";
        string fileName = "038851711563975.voistat";

        Console.WriteLine("fileNamePath:"+fileNamePath);
        Console.WriteLine("fileName:" + fileName);
        Console.ReadLine();

        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<PatientVOIstat>();
        var result = engine.ReadFile(fileNamePath + fileName);

        {
            // The engine is IEnumerable

            foreach (var VOI in result)
            {
                // your code here
                Console.WriteLine("Volume, mL: "+VOI.Volume);
                Console.WriteLine("Area, cm2: "+VOI.SurfaceArea);
                Console.WriteLine("Fractal dimension: "+VOI.FractalDimension);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of data reached");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}


}
```

The second part is created as C# class PatientVOIstat.cs in VS and is the following:

```
using FileHelpers;
using FileHelpers.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VOISTATread
{
//class Layout
//{
//}
[DelimitedRecord("\t")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class PatientVOIstat : INotifyRead
{
    // public int CustId;
    //public string Name;
    //public decimal Balance;

    // [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    // public DateTime AddedDate;

    public string Component;
    public string File;
    public string PatientName;
    public string PatientID;
    public string PatientInfo;
    public string StudyDescription;
    public string SeriesDescription;
    public string StudyDate;
    public string Color;
    public string VoiName;
    public double Time;
    public double Averaged;
    public double Sd;
    public double Volume;
    public double TotalSUM;
    public double TotalAVRVOL;
    public double MinimumVal;
    public double MaximumVal;
    public int NumberOfPixels;
    public int NumberOfEffectivePixels;
    public double HotAveraged;
    public double Stdv;
    public double Q1;
    public double Median;
    public double Q3;
    public double AreaUnderCurve;
    public double HypoxiaIndex;
    public double HypoxicVolume;
    public double NumberOfNaNs;
    public double VolumeWithoutNaNs;
    public double SurfaceArea;
    public double Sphericity;
    public double DiameterMax;
    public double FractalDimension;
    public double FD_LConfidenceInterval;
    public double FD_HConfidenceInterval;

    public void BeforeRead(BeforeReadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RecordLine.StartsWith("#") ||
           e.RecordLine.StartsWith("/"))
            e.SkipThisRecord = true;
    }
    public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs e)
    {
        // seems weird, but you have to handle this, even if nothing is done.
        //  we want to drop all records with no freight
        //if (Freight == 0)
        //    e.SkipThisRecord = true;

    }

}

}
```

There are examples in FileHelpers.net for other types of text file handling. There is VSIX extension to install, or you can place FileHelpers as Nudget package. 
Thank you Henrik for suggestion of FileHelpers.net. You do not need all using statements. 
Regards 
Marcin